# Kubernetes ingress nginx redirect to https

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

To redirect any HTTP traffic to HTTPS on tls enabled hosts, I have added the below annotation to my ingress resources

```
nignx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
```

With this when I curl the host in question, I get redirected as expected

[image]

But when I use a browser, the request to HTTP times out.

Now, I am not sure if it's something I am doing wrong at Nginx ingress conf as curl works?
Any pointers please? Thanks!

complete annotaiotns:

```
   annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

rules

```
 rules:
  - host: hostX
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svcX
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  - host: hostY
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svcX
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostX
  - hosts:
    - hostY
    secretName: hostY-secret-tls
```

Note:

1. The curl mentioned is to hostY in the rule above.
2. HTTPS to hostY via browser works and so cert is valid one.

Comment: At least two things: your snippet shows `...force-ssl-redirect: true` but annotations should be strings; in your "complete" config, you have both `force-ssl-redirect: "true"` _(now correctly a string)_ and `ssl-redirect: "false"` which is unlikely to do what you want; and the details matter about how you are testing with `curl` versus testing with your browser, so kindly edit your question to include those details. Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @mdaniel have mentioned your snippet shows `nignx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true` but annotations should be strings. Notice that in your "complete" config, you have both `force-ssl-redirect: "true"`  *(now correctly a string)* and `ssl-redirect: "false"` .

Simply remove annotation  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` and leave just `nignx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"`
Also enable [`--enable-ssl-passthrough`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/). This is required to enable passthrough backends in Ingress objects.

Your annotation should look like:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
```

If you defined hosts under TLS section they are going to be accessible only using https. HTTP requests are being redirected to use HTTPS. That is why you cannot access host via HTTP. Also you have to specify secret for host `hostX`, otherwise the default certificate will be used for ingress. Or if you don't want to connect to host `hostX` via HTTPS simply create different ingress without TLS section for it.

Take a look: .

Comment: As it turns out, it was a problem at the client-side, a proxy setting of the org, nothing to do with nginx-ingress or k8s.
As for the answer, it points out the typo of config in the question which is correct, so I will accept it. Thanks!